# Issues in posting ejs form data to controller

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, ejs

> i have gone through "http://tanmaysarkar.com/html-form-with-ejs-template-in-nodejs/" this post but i have written my logic in controller
>
> i am using mean stack with ejs template engine , i want to post ejs form data to ctroller which is under controller folder i dont how to post it to controller please help the following is ejs template, login.ejs is under views folder

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
    <div class="form-container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <% if(locals.error) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= error %></div>
        <% } %>
        <% if(locals.success) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-success"><%= success %></div>
        <% } %>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<%= locals.username || '' %>" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                <a href="/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

> on post of this following controller should get called
>
> In controllers/login.controller.js i have written following post req

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    // authenticate using api to maintain clean separation between layers
    request.post({
        url: config.apiUrl + '/users/authenticate',
        form: req.body,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            return res.render('login', { error: 'An error occurred' });
        }

        if (!body.token) {
          //console.log("inside if loop " + body.token + "::" + req.body.username + "::" + body)
            return res.render('login', { error: body, username: req.body.username });
        }

        // save JWT token in the session to make it available to the angular app
        req.session.token = body.token;

        // redirect to returnUrl

        var returnUrl = req.query.returnUrl && decodeURIComponent(req.query.returnUrl) || '/';
        console.log("return url" + returnUrl);
        res.redirect(returnUrl);
        //res.render('register')

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just had to add

```
    var ejs = require('ejs');
var login = require(__dirname + '/views/login.ejs');//for ejs
var logincontroller = require(__dirname + '/controllers/login.controller.js');//for ejs
```

above three lines in "server.js" which is entry point of my application and when i am actually posting the data mapping was needed like

```
app.use('/controllers/login.controller.js', logincontroller);//for ejs
```

and in my ejs file

```
<form method="post" action="/controllers/login.controller.js">
```

was required